# How can I install list from English template in German SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, list-template, localization, language-pack

I have a list, that was customized with InfoPath. I exported it as template and wanted to create list from this template in another server.

The original list was created in SharePoint with English language. Now, the target server is in German language. My English list templates are not available in "Apps you can add".

How can I create the list in German server? InfoPath won't deploy list to another URL, and recreating list in InfoPath would be possible but mean enormous amount of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution to my problem here:

http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2012/05/copy-sharepoint-lists-between-sites.html

TLDR:

1. unpack stp file,
2. change language code in manifest.xml,
3. repack file with makecab